# option "ASP.NET Web Configuration" tool is missing

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2019

i am using Visual Studio 2019 but I can't see any option "ASP.NET Web Configuration" tool as in previous versions of Visual studios

Comment: Does this help? [Accessing the ASP.NET Web Configuration Tool in Visual Studio 2013](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/accessing-the-asp-net-web-configuration-tool-in-visual-studio-2013/)

Comment: what is the error message?